# Sylius Standard 1.7 Fixtures: Where is the list of available options?

Tags: documentation, fixtures, sylius

How do you get the list of available options in sylius_fixtures.yaml? I can't find documentation of that anywhere. There must be a list somewhere: when I try to use an "illegal" parameter, there's an error message that lists all the available parameters for that particular node:

```
> Unrecognized option "menu_taxon" under "channel.custom.my-channel".
> Available options are "account_verification_required", "
> base_currency", "code", "color", "contact_email", "currencies",
> "default_locale", "default_tax_zone", "enabled", "hostname", "lo
> cales", "name", "shop_billing_data", "skipping_payment_step_allowed",
> "skipping_shipping_step_allowed", "tax_calculation_strategy",
> "theme_name".
```

It would be more practical to have a complete list rather than generate an error on purpose every time.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `bin/console debug:container --tag=sylius_fixtures.fixture` will list all configured fixtures.

Docs about fixtures configuration: https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusFixturesBundle/custom_fixture.html#configurable-fixture

Docs about the built-in fixtures: https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/book/architecture/fixtures.html#what-data-is-loaded-by-fixtures-in-sylius